# jQuery Slider/Accordion Combination

Tags: jquery, slider, accordion

I'm trying to make a section on a website for client testimonials whereby once clicked the text area expands over a corresponding image with the testimonial. Alone this would be straight forward enough using a simple slider but we are trying to incorporate into this an accordion menu. To add extra complications the testimonials are only contained within one tab of the accordion menu. Please see the attached image to gain a better understanding:

http://i55.tinypic.com/o08cqv.png
(This image is to demonstrate the concept only)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

is this the kind of thing you are looking to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/hollandben/HLSkW/

Also, you can use this jQuery plugin...

http://www.slidorion.com